# LibGDX — How to detect if 3d object was clicked on?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to make a simple bit of code that will detect whether a model was clicked on. So far the best method I've seen is to create some sort of rectangle around the mesh and detect with `Gdx.input.justTouched()` to get the x,y coordinates, and then check if the rectangle `contains` the coordinates returned by `justTouched()`.

I have no idea if there's a better way to do this, some kind of mesh onClick listener or something that LibGDX has in place that I'm unaware of (I've been scouring Google and the javadocs but I can't seem to find anything). I don't really need to deal with the z-axis coordinate, at least I don't think so. I only have the one `PerspectiveCamera` and it's not going to be moving around that much (not sure if this matters?)

Anyways, in my `render()` method I have:

```
if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
    //this returns the correct values relative to the screen size
    Vector2 pos = new Vector2(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY());

    //I'm not sure how to get the correct rectangle to see what the
    //width and height are for the model relative to the screen?
    Rectangle modelBounds = new Rectangle(<<not sure what to put here>>);

    if (modelBounds.contains(pos.x, pos.y) {
        System.out.println("Model is being touched at: " + pos.x + ", " + pos.y);
    }
}
```

I'm **really** not sure if this is the correct way to do this. I can get the position of the model with:

```
modelInstance.getNode("Node1").globalTransform.getTranslation(new Vector3());
```

but I'm not sure how to get the width and height as a rectangle relative to the screen size, if it's even *possible*.

I'm also unsure if this would cause massive lag, as I'm going to have about 7 nodes total that I need to detect if they're clicked on or not.

Is there a better way to do this? If not, is there a way to get the model width & height relative to the screensize (or camera, maybe)?

**EDIT:** Read about using Bounding Boxes, seems like what I need. Not quite sure how to implement it properly, however. I've changed my code to such:

```
public ModelInstance modelInstance;
public BoundingBox modelBounds;

@Override
public void create() {
    ...
    //omitted irrelevant bits of code
    modelInstance = new ModelInstance(heatExchangerModel);
    modelBounds = modelInstance.calculateBoundingBox(new BoundingBox());
}

@Override
public void render() {
    ...
    if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
        Vector3 pos = new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
        System.out.println(pos);
        if (modelBounds.contains(pos)) {
        System.out.println("Touching the model");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not really sure what the output of BoundingBox is supposed to be, or how the numbers it gives me correlates to the position in a 2d space. Hmm..

**EDIT2:** Think I'm getting closer.. Read about Rays and the `.getPickRay` method for my `PerspectiveCamera`. `.getPickRay` seems to return completely unusable numbers though, like *really* tiny numbers. I think I need to do something like:

```
if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
    Vector3 intersection = new Vector3();

    Ray pickRay = perspectiveCamera.getPickRay(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY());
    Intersector.intersectRayBounds(pickRay, modelBounds, intersection);
}
```

and then `intersection` should give me the point where they overlap. It appears to be not working, however, giving me really small numbers like `(4.8066642E-5, 2.9180354E-5, 1.0)` .. hmmm..